# Symfony3 auditing controllers

Tags: security, audit, symfony

I was trying to implementing security audit in controllers in symfony3. Requirements Similar to EntityAudit in https://github.com/simplethings/EntityAudit

Case Illustration:  /{_locale}/introduction.{_format} page has access needs to keep log the following information to the database table.
a. locale used 
b. format requested
c. is anonymous request or authorized as
d. request time

On the same time, the "counter" table increments the request "hit counter" of the controller.

What would be the best practice, just few line code or reference documents would be enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would prefer to use `EventListener` it would be less footprint.

Using an `EventListener` is a best practice such following cases. Sending Email to audits, tracking information, logging, exceptions, API subscribing etc.

So you can add a listener to your `services.yml` as following.

```
acme.demo.listener.your_listener:
    class: Acme\DemoBundle\EventListener\YourListener
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest }
```

Please see more detailed information. http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/event_listener.html

Use following whether is user anonymous or authenticated user :

`Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\AnonymousToken;` and

```
Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;
```

You can get locale from event request

```
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
```

For format there is a method `getRequestFormat()`  on GetResponseEvent's request object. 
RequestTime is just the `new \DateTime()`

So everything would be fine.